# Error when doing anything else than SELECT with node-firebird in Electron app

Tags: node.js, async-await, electron, firebird, async.js

We have to rebuild an app that import data from various DB and insert them in our DB, in Firebird 3 (with node-firebird).

When running in a NodeJS project, with Express, it worked fine.

Now, I'm writing a POC to embed the code in an Electron app.

Everytime I try to do anything else than a SELECT, the App crashes.

Here is the message :

```
Error

at doCallback (index.js:1234)
at index.js:2929
at messages.js:126
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141)
```

I don't have any other message.

We're using Electron 4.0.5, Node 10, Firebird 3.0.4 (32 bits)
Node-firebird

We also tried : node-firebird-dev but no success

The is a simple code example (using "manukdadali", a async wrapper on node-firebird).

```
const firebird = require('manukdadali');
const path = require('path');
const moment = require('moment');

class TestDB {
  constructor(folder) {
    this.options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      database: path.resolve(folder),
      user: 'SYSDBA',
      password: 'masterkey',
    };
  }

  insertData = async () => {
    const db = await firebird.connect(this.options);

    let rows = await db.query('select * from t_client');
    console.log(rows);
    try {
      rows = await db.query(
        `insert into t_client 
         (t_client_id, 
          matricule,
          nom,
          prenom,
          nom_jeune_fille,
          date_naissance,
          rang_gemellaire,
          langue,
          sexe,
          maison,
          etage,
          chambre,
          lit,
          commentaire_individuel,
          commentaire_global,
          t_profil_remise_id,
          t_personne_referente_id,
          facturation,
          date_derniere_visite
          ) values (
            4,
            '000233532',
            'NAME',
            'NAME2',
            'NAME3',
            '19700504',
            1,
            'FR',
            'M',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            1,
            1,
            '1',
            ''  
          )`);  
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error); 
    }

  };
}

export { TestDB };
```

Comment: Does the insert execute correctly when trying it in ISQL (or another query tool), for example I find it suspicious that you are inserting an empty string into a column called `date_derniere_visite`, which suggests it is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` column, where empty string is not a valid value. Also given, an insert doesn't produce rows, assigning to `rows` is weird here, but I'm not sure if that would cause an error.

Comment: Hi Mark.  Thank you for the answer.
Yes, I can insert, update, execute a stored proc in ISQL.
The problem is only within Electron.  The same operation within a simple Nodejs script works fine.

Comment: `rows = await db.query` - but rowset is only generated by SELECT query type. Why would you ever expect any other query to produce rowsets ???

Comment: indeed.  But that's not the point.  It should return "0", but not crashes.

Comment: why should it "return 0" when it should not return anything ?

Comment: I just removed the "rows" affectation.  Didn't change.

Comment: remove `await` then

Answer (score 1):

So, as I commented, it was linked to the processes in Electron.
In the rederer process, it was crashing.

I moved the DB access and operations to the MAIN process and it works perfectly.
I use IPC communication between renderer and main, for now.

Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

What `rowset` do expect to come from insert statement? What is there to be returned, more so, what multiple-rows results can there be from `insert` ?

```
 rows = await db.query(
    `insert into t_client ....
```

Just look at `Node-firebird` description - is pulling result rows a way to issue `INSERT` ?

- https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird
- https://libraries.io/github/hgourvest/node-firebird

Here is the example from there - it does NOT use rows:

```
// db = DATABASE
db.query('INSERT INTO USERS (ID, ALIAS, CREATED) VALUES(?, ?, ?) RETURNING ID', [1, 'Pe\'ter', new Date()],
 function(err, result) {
    console.log(result[0].id);
    db.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Alias=?', ['Peter'], function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        db.detach();
```

For the full overview of `Node Firebird` library use the built-in test module - it highlights all the intended methods of accessing the database and all the typical errors.

https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird/tree/master/test

---

The next culprit may be `await` modifier.

According to https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

> Note that await may **only** be used in functions **marked with the `async`** keyword. It works similarly to generators, suspending execution in your context until the promise settles

Was the function marked ?

https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird/blob/master/lib/index.js

```
Transaction.prototype.query = function(query, params, callback) {
```

So, was it marked with `async`, is this function nwritten in suspension-tolerant `Promise`-returning way? is it not.
Is there any other function in Firebird-Node library written with `async` flag? I could not find any.

Which should mean if you want to use some Firebird-Node code in async-await off-side mode you have to make your own `async`-aware functions and call database functions in usual non-`async` mode inside those functions, and only pass your special `async`-ready wrappers to the `await`.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the code, using ONLY node-firebird ......

```
const firebird = require('node-firebird');
const path = require('path');
const moment = require('moment');

class TestDB {
  constructor(folder) {
    this.options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      database: path.resolve(folder),
      user: 'SYSDBA',
      password: 'masterkey',
      port: 3050,
      lowercase_keys: false, 
      role: null,
      pageSize: 4096,
    };
  }

  getGlients = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      this.db.query('select * from t_client', (err, res) => {
        resolve(res);
      })
    })
  };

  connectDb = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebird.attach(this.options, (err,db) => {
        resolve(db)
      });
    });
  };

  insertData = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.execute(
        `insert into t_client 
         (t_client_id, 
          matricule,
          nom,
          prenom,
          nom_jeune_fille,
          date_naissance,
          rang_gemellaire,
          langue,
          sexe,
          maison,
          etage,
          chambre,
          lit,
          commentaire_individuel,
          commentaire_global,
          t_profil_remise_id,
          t_personne_referente_id,
          facturation,
          date_derniere_visite
          ) values (
            4,
            '000233532',
            'NAME',
            'NAME2',
            'NAME3',
            '19700504',
            1,
            'FR',
            'M',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            1,
            1,
            '1',
            ''  
          )`
      , (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(res);
      });
    })


  }

  launchTest = async () => {
    this.db = await this.connectDb();
    console.log(this.db)
    let rows = await this.getGlients();
    console.log(rows);
    try {
      const res = await this.insertData();
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

export { TestDB };
```

the result is the same.

[image: Here are the 3 "console.log" ouputs]

Comment: can you use some debugger into NPM modules ?  set the breakpoint inside the `doCallback` function of `node-firebird` and see what happens inside. At line 1234 it seems to do some secondary check `if (isError(obj)) ....` after the primary check `if (obj instanceof Error)` was passed without triggering. Try to open debugger there and see what actually data came into the function (both with and without Electron - there may be difference) and where expectations fail

Comment: for what I can see in sources, it should get triggered when `obj.status` is non-zero, and it seems to me that `status` member is used to transfer old-style Firebird error codes (GDS Code). Line 1234 however says `callback(new Error(obj.message))` thus loosing `obj.status` and potentially generating secondary errors on missing or non-expected `.message` values

Comment: 1) can you try doing the same on Firebird 2.5 ? 2) does Electron do some extra multi-threading ? could it be that firebird connection is created in one thread, but the request is done in some other thread?

Comment: Yes, I can try with Firebird 2.5.
But as we use the packages in Firebird 3, it would not be a usable solution.
I'll test and report the results here.

Thaks to everyone.

Comment: Indeed, I suspect that the problem is linked to Electron's threads .... But I'm not sure.

Comment: I heard that this js package has problems with new FB3 "wire protocol" and that it was de facto abandoned, and some other people started some other js package instead

Comment: I solved it :)

I moved the DB operation the the MAIN process.
I'm, for now, using IPC communication.  It works well.

Comment: Great! You said you uses some await-wrapper over node-firebird. Maybe you'd somehow reach its author, if it is still maintained. Just to make it work with Electron or to explicitly deny working with Electron. Seems (almost random guess) the trick is largely about multi-threading and coordination between FB-related JS-objects (connection->transaction(s)->querie(s)->parameters and rowsets) - they somehow spread across different threads, which wrapper or Electron should probably prevent form.